# Save Multi Select Choice Chips selected/unselected state in an alert-dialog

Tags: flutter

I am filtering results in my application based off of the multichoice chips that are selected. I have it filtering results properly, however when I select the done button in the alert dialog it does not save the selected state of the choice chips. It also does not clear the selected states of the choice chips when I hit the clear button. Any recommendations?

MultiFilterChoiceChips Class:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class MultiFilterChips extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> filterList;
  final Function(List<String>) onSelectionChanged;

  MultiFilterChips(this.filterList, {this.onSelectionChanged});

  @override
  _MultiFilterChipsState createState() => _MultiFilterChipsState();
}

class _MultiFilterChipsState extends State<MultiFilterChips> {

  List<String> selectedFilters = List();

  _buildFilterList() {
    List<Widget> filters = List();

    widget.filterList..forEach((item){
      filters.add(Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
        child: ChoiceChip(
          label: Text('$item'),
          selected: selectedFilters.contains(item),
          onSelected: (selected) {
            setState(() {
              selectedFilters.contains(item)
                  ? selectedFilters.remove(item)
                  : selectedFilters.add(item);
              widget.onSelectionChanged(selectedFilters);
            });
          },
        ),
      ));
    });
    return filters;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      children: _buildFilterList(),
    );
  }

}
```

Filter Pressed (App Bar Icon) Alert Dialog:

```
  _filterPressed() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            scrollable: true,
            title: Text('Filter Scouts'),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Rank:'),
                _multiFilterRankChipState(),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5)),
                Text('Patrol:'),
                _multiFilterPatrolChipState(),
              ],
            )),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Clear"),
                onPressed: () {
                  filter = ""; //ranks filter string to send to the sqlite database
                  pfilter = ""; //patrol filter string to send to the sqlite database
                  setState(() {
                    selectedRanks.clear(); //List<String> that holds the selected ranks 
                    selectedPatrols.clear(); //List<String> that holds the selected patrols



                    //sends the query to the database and resets the future list builder state
                    // back to initial state without filters

                    _searchResults(searchText); 
                  });
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Done"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  })
            ],
          );
        });
  }
```

Rank MultiFilter Call:

```
  _multiFilterRankChipState() {
    return MultiFilterChips(ranks, onSelectionChanged: (selectedList) {
      setState(() {
        //selectedList = selectedRanks;
        selectedRanks = selectedList;
        debugPrint("SELECTED LIST ${selectedRanks.toString()}");
        _RanksFilterSet();
      });
    });
  }
```

For getting the list of Patrols I am getting the distinct list from the sqlite database as the list patrols change overtime thus using a future builder to get the list of strings:

Patrol MultiFilter Call:

```
 _multiFilterPatrolChipState() {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
        future: patrols(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return MultiFilterChips(snapshot.data,
                onSelectionChanged: (selectedList) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedPatrols = selectedList;
                    _PatrolFilterSet();
                  });
                });
          }
          return Container(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
                strokeWidth: 7,
              ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Let me know if you need more code! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selected items in a Map. In this sample, multi-select mode will start on long press of an item. Multi-select mode will stop when there's no selected items left.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var selectMode = false;

  Map<String, bool> listItemSelected = {
    'List 1': false,
    'List 2': false,
    'List 3': false,
    'List 4': false,
    'List 5': false,
    'List 6': false,
    'List 7': false,
    'List 8': false,
    'List 9': false,
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          children: listItemSelected.keys.map((key) {
            return Card(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  // if multi-select mode is true, tap should select List item
                  if (selectMode && listItemSelected.containsValue(true)) {
                    debugPrint('onTap on $key');
                    setState(() {
                      listItemSelected[key] = !listItemSelected[key];
                    });
                  } else {
                    // Stop multi-select mode when there's no more selected List item
                    debugPrint('selectMode STOP');
                    selectMode = false;
                  }
                },
                // Start List multi-select mode on long press
                onLongPress: () {
                  debugPrint('onLongPress on $key');
                  if (!selectMode) {
                    debugPrint('selectMode START');
                    selectMode = true;
                  }
                  setState(() {
                    listItemSelected[key] = !listItemSelected[key];
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  // Change List item color if selected
                  color: (listItemSelected[key])
                      ? Colors.lightBlueAccent
                      : Colors.white,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Text(key),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Demo

[image: demo]